# How to duplicate name_ids over a date range

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to take a list of name IDs and duplicate them over a range of 25 months, so if I had 100 names, I want to end up with 2500 rows. I'm fairly new to SQL in general, so I'm having some trouble with it.

I'm using a query to generate the row of dates based on the row number of a table. The data set I'm using doesn't have dates associated with the name IDs, so I can't join them.

```
select distinct to_date(date_part(month, d.n) 
|| '/' 
|| date_part(year, d.n), 'MM/YYYY') AS daten
select (getdate()::date - row_number() over (order by true))::date as n
from any_table) as d
where datediff(mm, daten, current_date) < 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you're trying to achieve, but the query you posted does not work for me.

Basically If you want to get all permutations of two tables you basically want to perform a `CROSS JOIN` operation.

I re-wrote the query to what I understood you wanted to achieve. Let me know if that's not it.

```
with months as (
    select to_char(dateadd(month, - row_number() over (), current_date), 'MM/YYYY') as month
    from base_zalon_backend.request
    limit 5 -- gives you last 5 months (including current month)
), ids as (
    select 'id_1' as id UNION ALL
    select 'id_2' union all
    select 'id_3' union all
    select 'id_4' union all
    select 'id_5'
)
select * from months cross join ids order by month, id
```

returns:

```
month   id
01/2019 id_1
01/2019 id_2
01/2019 id_3
01/2019 id_4
01/2019 id_5
02/2019 id_1
02/2019 id_2
02/2019 id_3
02/2019 id_4
02/2019 id_5
03/2019 id_1
03/2019 id_2
03/2019 id_3
03/2019 id_4
03/2019 id_5
04/2019 id_1
04/2019 id_2
04/2019 id_3
04/2019 id_4
04/2019 id_5
05/2019 id_1
05/2019 id_2
05/2019 id_3
05/2019 id_4
05/2019 id_5
```

Comment: Yeah, that output looks right for what I want, each ID has a month row for each month in the range. I'll test it out later today at work, and I'll let you know how it turned out. Thanks for being able to interpret my madness. I'm kinda self-learning postgres and finding Redshift (what my work uses) has some... limitations.

Comment: My only question is, do I have to select each ID manually (i.e. write a select statement for each one?), because I'd be working with about 50k entries before I was able to pare them down.

Comment: Dude, you're the man. This absolutely worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Of course you don't have to _ select each ID manually (i.e. write a select statement for each one?)_. Just `SELECT` from a proper table. I used this table constructed using `SELECT ... UNION ALL ...` just to be able to get a running query without a real table behind it. Just be careful with `CROSS JOIN` - it's feasible to cross join 50k with 1k, but 1M with 5k may not.